# javascript unbind dom events

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, xss, unbind

I'm working on a web framework and am trying to build XSS prevention into it. I have set it up so it will escape incoming data for storage in the database, but sometimes you want to save html that the user generates. I am trying to make a custom tag that will prevent any javascript from executing, here is my first hack at it:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <preventjs>
      <div id="user-content-area">
        <!-- evil user content -->
          <p onclick="alert('evil stuff');">I'm not evil, promise.</p>
          <p onmouseover="alert('evil stuff');">Neither am I.</p> 
        <!-- end user content -->
      </div>
    </preventjs>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // <preventjs> tags are supposed to prevent any javascript events
      // but this does not unbined DOM events
      $("preventjs").find("*").unbind();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I tried using jQuery to unbind everything, but it doesn't unbind events in the DOM, which is exactly what I'm trying to do. Is it possible to unbind all events for a DOM element?

Comment: But what if the javascript is just within a script tag.  It will execute before you can even attempt to clean it.

Comment: I was planning on removing script tags before saving the data, those are easy enough to detect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're problem is that you are doing this on the wrong end of things -- you should be filtering all user input of potentially hostile content **when you receive it**.

The first rule of thumb when doing this is "always whitelist, never blacklist".  Rather than allowing any and all attributes in your user-generated HTML, simply keep a list of allowed attributes and strip away all others when you receive the HTML (possibly on the client side -- definitely on the server side.)

Oh, and HTML is not a regular language. You'll want to use an HTML parser, not a regular expression for this task.

Comment: Can you recommend an HTML parser? I'm coding everything in PHP on the server side.

Comment: @regality -- see the answers to this question for some good ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php

Answer (score 2):

`.unbind` will only unbind events attached using jQuery. You can get rid of inline event handler code by setting them to null, e.g.:

```
$("preventjs *").removeAttr("onclick").removeAttr("onmouseover");
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bkgx2/)

EDIT: Here's an evil solution, you can remove all attributes starting with "on":

```
$("preventjs *").each(function() {
    var attribs = this.attributes;
    var that = this;
    $.each(attribs, function(i, attrib) {
        if(attrib.name.indexOf("on") === 0) {
            $(that).removeAttr(attrib.name);
        }
    });
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bkgx2/1/)

Comment: I thought of doing something like that, but there are a lot of obscure events that I don't want to hunt down, keep track of, and keep up to date.

Comment: That's creative. Are there any attributes that could slip through or that would be removed and shouldn't?

Comment: @regality - I don't know, are there any non-eventy ones which start with "on"? I doubt it.

Comment: @karim - the only issue with this is the `onload` and `onerror` attributes, which will fire before this code can get to it - otherwise, quite impressive!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've inline handlers. `unbind` cannot remove inline handlers.

```
<p onclick="alert('evil stuff'...
   ^^^^
```

To remove inline handlers, use `removeAttr`

```
$("preventjs").find("*").removeAttr('onclick');
$("preventjs").find("*").removeAttr('onmouseover');
```

Comment: @Joey, you need to include jQuery or it won't.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't paying attention

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind the events individually:

```
$('p').each(function(){ this.onclick = this.onmouseover = undefined; });
```

If you want to unbind other events like mouseout you have to add them to that list:

```
$('p').each(function(){ this.onclick = 
                          this.onmouseover = 
                            this.onmouseout = undefined; });
```

Of course you'll want to use a selector other than `$('p')`, I just didn't want to put your other one because `preventjs` is not an HTML tag